# Google Chrome - not connecting when running from behind a proxy

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, proxy

I am having issues running the Google Chrome browser - version *25.0.1364.160 m* - from behind a proxy on a Windows 7 computer.

**What is the problem?**

When I try to open anything that isn't native to Chrome, the pages stay in a state of loading - ie, white page and tab says "New Tab" wth a slow anti-clockwise spinner.

**When does this happen?**

Whenever I try and use Chrome. No pages will load - this includes internet, intranet, local files and pages served from localhost.

**What about other browsers?**

Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE and even Google Chrome Canary work without an issue.

**Any other useful information?**

When I navigate to chrome://net-internals/#tests and fetch http://www.google.com/ then I get the following results:

[image: Chrome connection test suite results - fails when using system proxy settings and auto detecting settings]

**Additional Notes**

- When running the test suite in Google Chrome Canary, all tests pass.
- I have tried unintalling and re-installing Chrome
- The problem started occuring last week when I had to add some additional Windows Credentials to get any browser (except Firefox) to pass through the proxy
- When the problem first arose, and prior to adding the new Windows Credentials mentioned above, Chrome provided a pop-up box asking for the user credentials to connect to network (Chrome connected without a problem when entering credentials this way)

Comment: If all other browsers work except Chrome, it has to be either configuration-specific (reinstalling might not clear all config files) or specific to some kind of client firewall. Chunked encoding seems (after some googling) to usually be a server-specific error caused by corrupted bytes. Does the same thing happen with Chrome in safe mode with networking?